# Подключение необходимых заголовочных файлов в OpenSSL

Tags: c, include, openssl, sha

Доброго времени суток. Разбираю код [OpenSSL SHA256](https://gist.github.com/tsupo/112188/acdbf002acf454bd60c355a776b9a5b58b6dff5e): скопировал в VS2012, установил сам [OpenSSL](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), смотрю содержимое скаченного. Мне необходимо для компиляции программы подключить `openssl/x509.h` и `openssl/hmac.h`. Однако в папке `OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl` есть просто файлы `hmac.h` и `x509.h`. Интересно то, что если их открыть, то внутри стоят также хедеры с "префиксом" `openssl/...`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разрешить мою проблему? Может, я не там ищу?

EDIT 1. Собрал OpenSSL, подключаю библиотеку `libeay32.dll` и содержимое папки `include` к проекту. 
[image: Подключение папки <code>include</code>]
[image: подключение библиотеки через свойства проекта]

EDIT 2. В итоге OpenSSL правильно собрал и библиотеки подключились. Оставлю те проблемы, с которыми я столкнулся, и их решение.

Так как у меня x64, то скрипты, которыми надо запускать установку OpenSSL, надо писать для версии x64 (**запускать Visual Studio CMD из под администратора - это очень ВАЖНО**), а именно:
`perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=D:\finalOpenSSL`, где после `--prefix` идёт путь к папке, в которой мы найдём всё необходимое.
Далее

```
ms\do_win64a
nmake -f ms\nt.mak
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
nmake -f ms\nt.mak test
```

Если всё прошло успешно (не выскакивало никаких ERROR или Fatal ERROR, которыми так богат `nmake`), то в конце выполнения данной последовательности скриптов Вы увидите `passed all tests`. В папке, которые Вы в самом начале указали, будут папки `lib` и `include`. В первой нам нужен файл `libeay32.lib`, который нужно подключить в меню `компоновщик - ввод - дополнительные зависимости`. `include` нужно подключить в `C/C++ - общие - дополнительные каталоги подключаемых файлов`. Всё это, очевидно, можно найти в свойствах проекта. Обязательно стройте Release версию. 
**P.S** в скритпах указаны такие команды, которые необходимы для построение *статической* либы, так как именно *статическая* либа нужна для VS.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68714/discussion-on-question-by-setplus-----).